# GET encoding for static WMTSCapabilities.xml

Tags: wmts, ogc, zxy

Supposedly, one can turn a collection of static tiles, hosted according to the ZXY schema also used by OpenStreetMap tiles and Google Maps tiles, into a standard-conformant OGC WMTS by accompanying it by an (also static) `WMTSCapabilities.xml` file for satisfying the `GetCapabilities` WMTS operation.

Amongst others, this document describes how itself may be obtained:

> All WMTS servers operating in a procedure oriented architecture style
>   and using HTTP SHALL specify the message encodings that MAY be sent
>   using HTTP GET transfer of operation requests. Specifically, an
>   ows:Constraint parameter SHOULD be included, with "GetEncoding" as the
>   value of the "name" attribute and specifying the values allowed:
>
> a) The value "KVP" indicates that KVP encoding is allowed, when using
>   HTTP GET transfer as specified in clause 8.

If I understood correctly, hosting the static `WMTSCapabilities.xml` at an URL like `https://example.com/mymap/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml` means that the request to it would not be "KVP encoded" but "RESTful encoded". However, the standard only names "KVP" as a possible value.

So, if the `WMTSCapabilities.xml` is **only** made available at `https://example.com/mymap/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml`, not also at e.g. `https://example.com/mymap.cgi?service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities` (which would be an URL for a KVP request), should the operations metadata read

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
   <ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
      <ows:DCP>
         <ows:HTTP>
            <ows:Get xlink:href="https://example.com/map/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml">
               <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
                  <ows:AllowedValues>
                     <ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>
                  </ows:AllowedValues>
               </ows:Constraint>
            </ows:Get>
         </ows:HTTP>
      </ows:DCP>
   </ows:Operation>
   <!-- ... -->
</ows:OperationsMetadata>
<!-- ... -->
```

or just

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
   <ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
      <ows:DCP>
         <ows:HTTP>
            <ows:Get xlink:href="https://example.com/map/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml">
               <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
                  <ows:NoValues />
               </ows:Constraint>
            </ows:Get>
         </ows:HTTP>
      </ows:DCP>
   </ows:Operation>
   <!-- ... -->
</ows:OperationsMetadata>
<!-- ... -->
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the examples on the OGC site see http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/wmts-1_0_1.zip

We have: `wmtsGetCapabilities_response_RESTful.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This is an example of a GetCapabilities response that declares 
RESTful support for requesting tiles and FeatureInfo documents -->
...
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
    <ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
        <ows:DCP>
            <ows:HTTP>
                <ows:Get xlink:href="http://www.opengis.uab.es/cgi-bin/world/MiraMon5_0.cgi?">
                    <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
                        <ows:AllowedValues>
                            <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
                        </ows:AllowedValues>
                    </ows:Constraint>
                </ows:Get>
            </ows:HTTP>
        </ows:DCP>
    </ows:Operation>
```

In the other examples I don't see any instance of `<ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>` so probably you should discount it.

I see that this example uses .cgi? and your question is about some static file, but as in HTTP KVP unknown query parameters are ignored I think in doesn't matter.

i.e.

Both `https://example.com/map/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml` and `https://example.com/map/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?service=WMTS&request=GetCapabilities&` will return the capabilities response document.

Comment: I've seen `<ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>` in files generated by http://wmts.maptiler.com e.g. http://wmts.maptiler.com/aHR0cHM6Ly90aWxlLm9zbS5jaC9zd2l0emVybGFuZC97en0ve3h9L3t5fS5wbmc_/wmts, but as I haven't seen it in the standard, wondered whether that was allowed at all.

Comment: I've asked a related question w.r.t. `GetTile` at https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/255548/51574, in case you're interested.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to a folder hierarchy of tiles locally by defining a WMTSCapabilities.xml document at the top of that directory, and then connecting via a URL like "file://" or something?