# WMTS: declare "GetTile" operation for statically hosted tiles?

Tags: wmts, ogc, zxy

Supposedly, one can turn a collection of static tiles, hosted according to the ZXY schema also used by OpenStreetMap tiles and Google Maps tiles, into a standard-conformant OGC WMTS by accompanying it by an (also static) `WMTSCapabilities.xml` file for satisfying the `GetCapabilities` WMTS operation. (See also question [GET encoding for static WMTSCapabilities.xml](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/255528/51574).)

Amongst others, that XML document should describe how tiles can be obtained with parametrized URLs. If the tiles are **only** available at URLs like (say) `https://example.com/map/1/2/3.png` (this one being for zoomlevel 1, tile column 2, tile row 3) but **not** at any URLs like

```
https://example.com/map.cgi?service=WMTS&request=GetTile&version=1.0.0&layer=example&style=default&format=image/png&TileMatrixSet=WholeWorld_CRS_84&TileMatrix=1&TileRow=2&TileCol=3
```

then should the `ows:OperationsMetadata` have an entry for the `GetTile` operation like

```xml
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
   <!-- ... -->
   <ows:Operation name="GetTile">
      <ows:DCP>
         <ows:HTTP>
            <ows:Get xlink:href="https://tile.osm.ch/switzerland/">
               <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
                  <ows:AllowedValues>
                     <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
                  </ows:AllowedValues>
               </ows:Constraint>
            </ows:Get>
         </ows:HTTP>
      </ows:DCP>
   </ows:Operation>
</ows:OperationsMetadata>
```

or should *only* the `ResourceURL` elements of the respective `Layer` elements specify how to obtain tiles? The latter looks like

```xml
<Contents>
   <Layer>
      <ows:Title>My Map</ows:Title>
      <ows:Identifier>mymap</ows:Identifier>
      <ows:WGS84BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:2:84" dimensions="2">
         <ows:LowerCorner>-180 -85.051128779807</ows:LowerCorner>
         <ows:UpperCorner>180 85.051128779807</ows:UpperCorner>
      </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
      <Style isDefault="true">
         <ows:Identifier>default</ows:Identifier>
      </Style>
      <Format>image/png</Format>
      <TileMatrixSetLink>
         <TileMatrixSet>SOSM standard</TileMatrixSet>
      </TileMatrixSetLink>
      <ResourceURL format="image/png" resourceType="tile" template="https://example.com/map/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png" />
   </Layer>
   <!-- ... -->
</Contents>
```

, so `template="https://example.com/map/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png"` specifies where to find the tile, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `GetTile` operation includes

```
<ows:AllowedValues>
    <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
```

then you have to respond correctly to a KVP `GET` request or you are violating the standard.

If you plan on being a REST-only WMTS, then you should not offer a `GetTile` or `GetFeatureInfo` request in your capabilities.